# How do I query a list in a field?

Tags: kdb

I have a table of the form:

```
t                             p      s    c
----------------------------------------------------------
2019.08.06D13:29:45.746200000 4.5    4    (," ";,"T";,"I")
2019.08.06D13:29:58.413500000 4.5148 14   (," ";,"T";,"I")
2019.08.06D13:30:00.072000000 4.65   1522 (," ";,"O")
2019.08.06D13:30:03.681300000 4.5048 1    (," ";,"I")
2019.08.06D13:30:04.045200000 4.5    5    (," ";,"I")
```

I'm trying to grab the row at 13:00, that contains `"O"` in the column `c`.

I think it should be something like:

```
select from t where "O" in c
```

but it doesn't seem to work (null result). I've tried `raze` on this column too, but it doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Edit with `raze each c`:

```
2019.08.06D13:29:45.746200000 4.5    4    " TI"
2019.08.06D13:29:58.413500000 4.5148 14   " TI"
2019.08.06D13:30:00.072000000 4.65   1522 " O"
2019.08.06D13:30:03.681300000 4.5048 1    " I"
2019.08.06D13:30:04.045200000 4.5    5    " I"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `enlist"0"` as that is the form the c values take. In combination with each-right (`/:`) you can check if `enlist"0"` is in each c value:

```
q)t:([]c:(enlist each(" ";"T";"I");enlist each(" ";"T";"I");enlist each(" ";"O");enlist each(" ";"I");enlist each(" ";"I")))
q)select from t where enlist["O"]in/:c
c
---------
," " ,"O"
```

No need for the `enlist` if you raze the result:

```
q)select from(update raze each c from t)where"O"in/:c
c
----
" O"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach for this simple example with index:

```
q)select from t where c[;1;0] = "O"
c
---------
," " ,"O"
```

Although likely this could be broken if you aren't looking for "O" to be the 2nd item in each list. Also note this only works with `=` because it gets down to a character instead of a string (which is a list of characters)